# How can I switch the content when I click button?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to switch the content when I click button A or B.I wrote html

```
  <h4>SELECT</h4>
  <div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>A</label>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>B</label>
  </div>
```

I want to switch the content if

```
<input type="radio">
<label>A</label>
```

is clicked,`<label>a</label>` is shown,and if

```
<input type="radio">
<label>B</label>
```

is clicked,`<label>b</label>` is shown.I want to do it by using jQuery but how should I write the codes?I am very new to jQuery,so please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Being new just means you have some learning to do. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you attempt this yourself? If you did, then share what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below logic where you can show next label of clicked radio button.

hide all label initially and put name="switch" to radio button so that at a time once will be selected

```js
$(function(){
  $('input:radio[name=switch]').on('click', function(){
      $(this).siblings('label').hide();
      $(this).next('label').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>SELECT</h4>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="switch">
    <label style="display:none">A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="switch">
    <label style="display:none">B</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

İf u change just to click radio button try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#radioone").click(function(){
    $(".textone").html("<label>Adana merkez patlıyor herkes!</label>");
  });
  $("#radiotwo").click(function(){
    $(".texttwo").html("<label>Adana merkez patlıyor herkes!</label>");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I think I got lost in translation. Do you mean that you want to switch on selected radio buttons by clicking on their labels?

The "normal" way to do it, is to bind the "for" attribute of a Label to the id of a radio button like:

```
<div>
   <input type="radio" id='radio1'><label for='radio1'>A</label>
   <input type="radio" id='radio2'><label for='radio2'>B</label>
</div>
```